# Can i use 47 kilohm potentiometer instead of 50 kilohm potentiometer?

Tags: potentiometer

I am trying to build a circuit from a schematic I found on Internet. The circuit uses 50 kΩ potentiometer. But I have only 47 kΩ potentiometer and 100 kΩ potentiometer with me. Can I use them instead of 50 kΩ potentiometer?. will the circuit work with them or will it fry the circuit?

Answer (score 5):

You don't provide the circuit but in general the tolerances on pots are very loose, like 10-20% so 47K is close enough to 50K in most every  practical case.

Nothing will "fry" as a result.

Comment: thanks for replying and for help

Answer (score 1):

More than likely yes. Without the circuit it is impossible to say but most standard types will have a tolerance of ±10% anyway.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fI4NPg.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Moving the wiper adjusts the voltage between V2 and V1. The output depends on the ratio of the resistance each side of the wiper (as well as whatever load is applied to the wiper).*

If it is being used as a potentiometer then the output voltage will be determined by the ratio of the resistances each side of the wiper rather than by their actual values.

Comment: thanks for replying and for help

Comment: No problem. Don't forget to upvote useful answers and "accept" one to indicate that your question has been answered.